# Blogger/Blogspot condition for showing date modified

Tags: xml, blogger

So i'm trying to write a condition thats basically says, if dateModified is not equal to datePost, show dateModified.

This works:

```
<data:post.lastUpdated/>
```

This works:

```
<data:post.date/>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<b:include cond='data:post.lastUpdated != data:post.date'>
  <data:post.lastUpdated/>
</b:include>
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `b:include` instead of `b:if`

```xml
<b:if cond='data:post.lastUpdated != data:post.date'>
  <data:post.lastUpdated/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: OMG, cant believe I did that.